# Where do I specify the filename to link to in FFI for Rust?

Tags: c, rust, ffi

I'm experimenting with FFI on Rust, but I can't find how you tell `cargo run` where to find your C code, after 2 hours of searching.

I know there's an FFI chapter in the Rust book, but it doesn't state *what should I pass to `cargo run` so that it knows that my C file is located at `./c/main.c`*.

Rust code:

```rust
#[link(name = "main")]
extern {
    fn a() -> u8;
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", unsafe {
        a()
    });
}
```

C code:

```c
char a() {
    return 'A';
}
```

Do I need to compile the C code to an `.o` file so that Rust can detect it? Where should I put it if I need to do so? I am on Windows.

I also tried adding a build script that prints `cargo:rustc-link-search=./` but that didn't fix it.

The error I get is:

```
ld: cannot find -lmain
```

Comment: https://crates.io/crates/cc

Comment: @Stargateur Yes? What about it?

Comment: Oh so I need to use that package to link the code? Would be nice if you can expand and post as an answer so I can mark the question as accepted

Comment: This example is not complete yet. Please include the Rust project's Cargo.toml and how you are currently compiling and linking the C project.

Comment: @E_net4 The Cargo.toml has not been touched since automatically created by cargo, and I'm not even *sure* how I should be compiling and linking the C project which is why I'm asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Cargo.toml should look like:

```
[build-dependencies]
cc = "1.0.32"
```

You should also have a build.rs located in the same folder as `Cargo.toml`:

```rust
extern crate cc;

fn main() {
    cc::Build::new()
        .file("src/main.c") //here I specify that main.c is in src folder, you can change the location likewise
        .compile("libmain.a");
}
```

Finally, `main.rs` has:

```
extern "C" {
    fn a() -> u8;
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", unsafe { a() });
}
```

After this, running `cargo run` will compile the C code and link it as a library, you might find these [examples](https://github.com/sn99/rust-ffi-examples/tree/master/rust-to-c) useful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190932/discussion-between-siddharth-naithani-and-firecubez).